# Code is moving on before my fetch is completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I'm having a problem where inside my useEffect whenever I call getRoomDetails, the code continues on before it's finished fetching data from my API. So it will create the Chess object with the default value I've given for boardState, instead of the updated value from my API. How could I get it so it waits until getRoomDetails finishes, before moving onto creating the Chess object.

```
    const initialState = {
    hostTime: 600,
    guestTime: 600,
    chessAnnotations: "",
    isHost: true,
    fen: "start",
}

const getRoomDetails = () => {
    fetch('/api/get-room?code=' + roomCode).then((response) =>
        response.json()
    ).then((data) => {
        const newObj = {
            hostTime: data.host_curr_time,
            guestTime: data.guest_curr_time,
            chessAnnotations: data.chess_annotations,
            isHost: data.is_host,
            fen: data.fen,
        };
        setBoardState(newObj);
        console.log(newObj)
    });
}

const [boardState, setBoardState] = useState(initialState);


let game = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    getRoomDetails();
    console.log(boardState.fen + "lit");
    game.current = new Chess(boardState.fen);
    console.log("0");
}, []);
```

Output:

```
start 0
0
Object { hostTime: "600.00", guestTime: "600.00", chessAnnotations: "sdf", isHost: false, fen: "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/3P4/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1" }
```

Comment: `fetch` executes async in JS which means this is entirely expected. You want to `await` fetch to make sure you can run code before and after.

Comment: you need to return fetch from `getRoomDetails` and the use `.then` when you call it.. and your code that should run after promise resolve should go inside the the callback

Comment: React setState is also asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the explanation in the inline comments

```
const initialState = {
    hostTime: 600,
    guestTime: 600,
    chessAnnotations: "",
    isHost: true,
    fen: "start",
}

const getRoomDetails = () => {
  // HERE:  Return the promise
    return fetch('/api/get-room?code=' + roomCode).then((response) =>
        response.json()
    ).then((data) => {
        const newObj = {
            hostTime: data.host_curr_time,
            guestTime: data.guest_curr_time,
            chessAnnotations: data.chess_annotations,
            isHost: data.is_host,
            fen: data.fen,
        };
        setBoardState(newObj);
        console.log(newObj)
    });
}

const [boardState, setBoardState] = useState(initialState);


let game = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    getRoomDetails()
    // HERE: run this block after the promise is resolved
    .then(() => {
        console.log(boardState.fen + "lit");
        game.current = new Chess(boardState.fen);
        console.log("0");
    });
}, []);
```